# Eclipse multiple keyboard shortcuts for the same command

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

Is it possible to bind more than one keyboard shortcut for the same function in Eclipse? In Netbeans, I can add alternative keyboard shortcuts. For example, the image shows that pressing either ctrl+numpad1 or ctrl+alt+numpad1 will trigger the Projects command: https://ibb.co/itrKFT

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Go

```
Window->Preferences->General->Keys
```

then select the command you would like to define your new key for (type it into the filter input field). Then press the ***"Copy Command"*** button. This will create a new command for which you can create a new keybinding.